# Регистр в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте. Кодировка таблицы `utf8_unicode_ci`, не учитывается регистр записей. То есть при поиске по полю `login = 'Oleg'` выдает строку с 'oleg'. Как учитывать регистр?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE BINARY `user`='Oleg'
```

Answer (score 1):

ну либо задать таблице кодировкe регистрозависимую. кодировка, оканчивающаяся на `_ci` регистронезависимая для выбрки